# Accessing files inside of docker container from an installed node package

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I'm developing an npm package that is installed into another node system.
This is all deployed in a docker container.

I need to access `/etc/files/` from my package, but I can't seem to get to access the files correctly.

When I do:

```js
readFileSync("/etc/files/fileIWant", "utf-8")
```

and then later install the package I get an error:

```js
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open `/data/node_modules/@package/packageName/dist/etc/files/fileIWant
```

I have also tried reading it with `path.join`:

```js
readFileSync(path.join(`/etc/files/`,`fileIWant`),"utf-8")
```

But this is still giving me the same error.

So I can see that it's prefixing the path I want to look at with the `/data/node_modules/...` which is not what I want. Since the files exist at `/etc/files/` in the docker container.

How do I specify that I want to read files from outside of the `node_modules`/`data` folders?

Comment: You should probably show us your Dockerfile, and whether that's the vanilla `fs.readFileSync` or something else, etc.

Comment: @AKX I don't have direct access to the Dockerfile. All I know is that the files are located at `/etc/files/` and that's where I want to read them from.

I'm using the `{readFileSync} from "fs"`, so the vanilla one I guess

Comment: Well, there's _something_ kooky about the Node system if it redirects your `readFileSync`s like this...

Comment: Yeah. I'm a bit lost. But it isn't something to do with the fact that this is an npm package that it in it's turn installed to an existing system?

Comment: I don't think so, because it's just code that gets placed into a `node_modules` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with path module node js.

you can do it like following code:

```
readFileSync(`${path.join(__dirname, '/etc/files/fileIWant')}`, "utf-8");
```

**I hope it'll helpful for you** :)

Comment: It's still giving the same error and trying to read from `open `/data/node_modules/@package/packageName/dist/etc/files/fileIWant`

Comment: @Gurkmeja101 Oh, that seems strange to me. Could you please share more information about your code? I'd like to help you.